# Will condensation occur in this condition?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I live in a tropical climate. I plan to build a house where the bedroom is next to the bathroom. The walls of both rooms are bricks, plastered and tiled from top to bottom. On the bedroom wall shared with the bathroom (remember both sides are tiled), I plan to build a wardrobe with no backside (the backside of the wardrobe will be the wall tiles).

The bathroom has passive ventilation but of course not conditioned, while the bedroom has air conditioner turned on only during bedtime. Outside temperature ranges from 29 degrees celcius at night to 37 degrees celcius at noon. I’m not really sure about indoor temperature without aircon, but when the aircon in the bedroom is turned on, it is usually set to 21 degrees celcius.

Will condensation form on the wall tiles inside the wardrobe at any point of the day?

Comment: This probably is a little too short on details (e.g., air circulation, temperature variations, etc) to be conclusively answered here. It also may violate the site policy on engineering-focused questions.

Comment: I wanted to ask on home improvement site, but I thought people with good knowledge of physics would provide more reliable answer. I will add more details you requested on the question.

Comment: Are you expecting the tiles of the wall next to the bathroom to be substantially colder than the rest of the room? If so, why?

Comment: No, but I was thinking that the tiles might get cold overnight because of the airconditioning. Will the condensation form as the room gets warmer after the aircon is turned off? I’m worried that the clothes might get moldy if it happens.